# D3 Ticks on x axis wrong

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have tried out some things but the ticks and the dates are still wrong formatted. on other charts I have it is working but not on this. How can the dates and the ticks be placed adequate?

Here is a fiddle of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/nv2qv2L2/

Here is the code of the tick format:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom").ticks(coverageArr.length).tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when making a time scale, you would use [`d3.time.scale()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#scale), rather than an ordinal scale.

1. Display time axis using time scales.

   Time scales let you specify directly the step you want for ticks. You do that by passing a d3 duration and a time interval to the .ticks() method of your axis. Like this:

   ```
   var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(d3.time.day, 4)
   ```

   You'll get the following result:
   [image]

You can find more about time intervals [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Intervals).

2. Display time axis using ordinal scales.

   ```
   var tickValues = [];
   for(i = 0; i < coverageArr.length; i++) {
     tickValues.push(coverageArr[i][0]);
   }
   var x = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(tickValues).rangeRoundBands([0, width], 1)
   ```

   Result will look as follows:
   [image]